# Add statistical significance between two groups for categorical boxplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to make a figure similar to the first screenshot (https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/categorical.html), but I would like to add a t-test value in the form of a star at the top of each x value as seen in the second screenshot (https://github.com/jbmouret/matplotlib_for_papers).
[image]
What would be the best way to generalize this to being able to do multiple x values in the second screenshot while still maintaining the stars in the second screenshot for each comparison?
[image]
Thanks!